# Correct use of for loop with array value as condition

Tags: c

Question: If the value of `x[0]`, for example, is being determined after the condition in the `for` loop is checked, how can you program the loop so that it stops when `x[0]` stores the value of the sentinel ?

```
printf("First Data Set: \n");   

for (int i = 0; x[i] != SENTINEL; i++) {        
    printf("Input Data Value %d> \n", i+1);     
    scanf_s("%f", &x[i]);                       
}
```

Comment: To loop until the user enters a set value is just strange. Why not just put the value in the array?

Comment: That's the crux of the problem statement, values stop getting added  to the array when the sentinel is entered, did you have a solution better than something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to check against the value you just entered. So you probably want to see the previous index in the loop condition making an exception (always evaluate to true) for the very beginning index:

```
for (int i = 0; i==0 || x[i-1] != SENTINEL; i++) {        
    printf("Input Data Value %d> \n", i+1);     
    scanf_s("%f", &x[i]);                       
}
```

Note that the code will not try evaluate `x[i-1]` at x of 0 (if the first operand of '||' has been evaluated to true then the second one is not attempted), so it's safe (provide that you have long enough x array).

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean by previous index making an exception, I tried to replace my condition with your suggestion but the loop wasn't ended.

Comment: exception here doesn't mean a C++ exception, it's just an exception of common 'rule' to fetch the previously entered value. Loop will end once a value equal to SENTINEL is scanned - isn't it what is expected?

Comment: I see what you mean now and it's logical, however the loop still doesn't end when the sentinel is entered for some reason

Comment: Fixed it, the format string for the scanf_s function was incorrect